# Latency fault injection in VertX / Spring framework applications at application level

Tags: microservices, vert.x, latency, chaos

I've checked [ChaosMonkey](https://codecentric.github.io/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/) which is only for springboot framework. Also, [Pumba tool](https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba) but, that looks like infrastructure level fault injection needing root system access.

I'm looking for help to induce latency fault inject at application level in VertX applications on openshift. Is there a recommended library/tool available to utilize?

Answer (score 2):

In 2018 I've presented at Codemotion Amsterdam an talk about chaos. For this talk I've used pumba and vert.x. Just for the record, ChaosMonkey is unrelated to Spring, it can be used with any application, but f you check the presentation https://www.jetdrone.xyz/presentations/codemotion-amsterdam-2018 you can see how to use pumba.

In a nutshell:

If you want to test for load/DDoS, you can use `wrk` or any other load test tool like:

```
wrk -t4 -c400 -d60s http://paas-myproject.127.0.0.1.nip.io/
```

You can test network outages:

```
# package loss
pumba --debug netem --duration 1m \
  --tc-image gaiadocker/iproute2 \
  loss -p 20 -c 10 "re2:.*paas.*"

# Introduce latency
pumba --debug netem --duration 1m \
  --tc-image gaiadocker/iproute2 \
  delay --time 500 "re2:.*paas.*"

# Introduce latency (2)
pumba --debug netem --duration 1m \
  --tc-image gaiadocker/iproute2 delay \
  --time 100 \
  --jitter 30 \
  --correlation 20 \
  "re2:.*paas.*"
```

Or server outages/crashes:

```
pumba --random --interval 1m \
  kill --signal SIGKILL "re2:.*paas.*"
```

Note that in all examples there's a regular expression `"re2:.*paas.*"`. This is to ensure that pumba will only affect the containers related to our application, not the other required containers from openshift or other applications.

For this you need to be sure your application is named in a simple way you can filter out when you perform:

```
docker ps
```